# NASM unable to open include file asm_io.inc. Doesn't it come with NASM?

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, nasm

I am not able to include the file **'asm_io.inc'** in Ubuntu.

I tried it in the follwing way :

```
%include 'asm_io.inc'
```

and issued the following command :

```
sudo nasm -f coff simple.asm
```

Error :

```
simple.asm:1: fatal: unable to open include file `asm_io.inc'
```

After searching on google, I tried variations like :

```
include 'asm_io.inc'

%include "~//includes//asm_io.inc"
```

I even searched root directory for file **asm_io.inc**, but it didn't show up.

But if I do not include the file **asm_io.inc** in other NASM code the assmebler works fine.

**My question :**

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, where exactly is the file asm_io.inc located on your hard drive?

Comment: @Michael block 0x4ff96c0 ;)

Comment: @Michael As i mentioned i have a working installation of NASM but still searching for asm_io.inc doesn't yield any result. Acc to U is it available with installation or i have to download it manually in the working directory ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using some code of Paul Carters tutorial. If this is the case you need to download asm_io.inc from http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/

Comment: I know that your link was correct at that time, but download page for source codes have changed. and I think it's a good idea to update this answer. This is the new correct url: http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/